# Icons I added disappear the next day

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, icons

I'm trying to develop a Java Swing project using NetBeans, but a day after I started, the icon I added on the buttons disappears. I put the button like this: button properties -> icon -> external image -> file select -> import to project -> ok. I don't use any code. Doesn't this change permanently? Why do the photos I added disappear?

Comment: I thought it was fixed when I said save them all but the application is not deleted when the application is opened and closed, but it is deleted when the computer is turned on and off. Please help. I put the movie posters on the buttons from the computer. But this 3rd disappearance is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem: my carelessness. While the photos were on the desktop, the path was on the desktop in netbeans. Later I put them in a folder. I forgot to change the new path. Problem solved.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please consider closing it, so that user, can spend time resolving unresolved issues. 